# Result of method() is ignored

Tags: java

I'm trying to change the value of static variable that I passed to `Klasa.method()` function and sadly return value is ignored.

```java
package com.company;

public class Klasa {
    public static int metoda(int x){
        x += 2;
        return x;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static int i = 10;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Main.i);
        Klasa.metoda(i);
        System.out.println(Klasa.metoda(i));
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've chosen the wrong language for that. The `x` within `metoda` is a copy by value.

Comment: What output are you getting and how is it different from what you expect?  You print out `i`, so it prints `10`.  You print out the return value of the method, so it prints `12`.  Then you print out `i` again, so it prints out `10` again.  What is confusing you?

Comment: Oh I see you're thinking of pass-by-reference.  We have a canonical for this.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of passing by reference, thanks Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of how Java works... Passing in i to your method will not change the value of i so you have reassign the value returned by the method to i:

```
i = Klasa.metoda(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are only passing the value of i to your method. You could solve it simply by changing

```
Klasa.metoda(i);
```

to

```
i = Klasa.metoda(i);
```